# ASP .NET MVC 2.0 or WebFoms to develop an auction site like Ebay?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I´d like to know what is the best option to develop an auction site like Ebay with ASP .NET 4.0:

- MVC 2.0
- WebForms

I only worked with WebForms, but I have time to learn MVC if is the best option...

What you think?

Comment: Can whoever voted this question down please comment to explain the reason behind the down-vote?

Comment: +1'd for general fairness. It's a reasonable question. Though probably very similar to many other "Compare WebForms 2 MVC" questions.

Comment: @Roberto, I don't understand why this would be down voted, and it doesn't make sense to down vote for no reason. I +1 to offset it.

Comment: Because its been asked a hundred times and SO is already filled with tons of information about webforms vs. mvc.   The answers are almost exact clones of other mvc vs webforms answers already on SO.  Cleaner Html markup. Check!  TDD is easier. Check!  How many times can this question be asked again and again?  The "Related Questions" duplicate check links for this questions title contains all the information you need to answer this question.

Comment: My question is about MVC or WebForms in a specific scenario... Maybe there is any peculiar factor in a Auction system that make one choice better than other...

Comment: @Paul What "particular factors" do auction sites have that is completely unique to auction sites?  Maybe you really wanted to ask a different question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/chad_myers/archive/2009/04/27/to-mvc-or-to-webforms.aspx has good arguments why you would want to use MVC over WebForms. You can read through the 4 bullet points and if they don't bother you then WebForms will be fine.

In a nutshell.

1. WebForms are fast to develop.
2. WebControls add ViewState and have
   PostBacks.
3. If you come from another language
   WebForms might not be OO enough for
   you.
4. WebForms are difficult to Unit Test

If you anticipate a high volume site then not having ViewState and being able to unit test should be important to you.

Answer (score 3):

MVC, but if you choose to use MVC do take the opportunity to write unit tests for your components.   May I suggest a Test Drive Design approach?

While you are at it, you might also want to look in to [Behavior Driven Design](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/03/behavior-driven-development-bdd-with-specflow-and-aspnet-mvc/) (it is like TDD, but few levels more abstracted)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend MVC, because I would recommend MVC for anything! It is easy to pick up, and you will probably never go back to webforms.

Besides the simplicity and the clean mark up. If you are working with any sort of generated code, the model binding makes developing pages really fast and easy. I have used a custom generated BLL and DLL, when the DataAnnotations attributes are generated all client side and server side validation is automatic.